# How to create a healthbar that responds to my health script?

Tags: user-interface, reference, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Hello Im using the New Unity 4.6 Ui tools to create a health bar,I've created healthbar textures, but I already have a health script thats using an Old OnGui Button funtion which displays a black button at the corner when hit on play, I want to disable the OnGui health sript texture and make that affect on my New healthbar UI textures. please help

```
//This is my health script that displays a black bar at the corner
var health = 300;

function OnGUI(){
if(GUI.Button(Rect(10,10,health,10), "")){
health += 25;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to hear you are still having trouble with this. Check out this image here. It shows where you can add the OnClick event to your new UI Button.
The part where you see UIManager just put the object that has your healthscript there and then you can access the event you want.
Just remove your OnGUI() code add a public function like

`public void GainHealth()
      {
         health +=25;
      }`

Once you have that changed you will see your function on the list like in the image here. be sure to set editor and runtime for it to work in editor. Once you set it there your button will do whatever function you set up there

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response again, I actually have a scroll value set up to my Canvas>img_header in the Component, Image type set as Filled, I want to access this image.fillAmount = .2f; with my player's health script, how to? I've added my own function Fill() but its not showing in the OnClickEvent :(

Comment: oh I achieved something like that using a slider.                                public Slider healthSlider; and then just set its value to health like so       healthSlider.value = currentHealth;

Comment: I just achieved it with the normal OnGui funciton! with the Gui skin I was able to put my own custom texture! sorry if I bothered you mate, thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Health bar system

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HealthSystem : MonoBehaviour {


    static float healthBarLenght = 20; //Fixed length



    public static void Set_HealthBar(
        Transform transform,
        int healthBarHeight,
        float CurrentHealth,
        float MaxHealth,
        Texture2D BackBar,
        Texture2D FrontBar)
    {
        Vector3 screenPosition;

        GUIStyle style1 = new GUIStyle();
        GUIStyle style2 = new GUIStyle();
        float HPDrop = (CurrentHealth / MaxHealth)* healthBarLenght;

        screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        screenPosition.y = Screen.height - screenPosition.y;

        style1.normal.background = BackBar;
        GUI.Box(new Rect(screenPosition.x-(healthBarLenght/2),screenPosition.y-20, healthBarLenght,healthBarHeight),"",style1);

        style2.normal.background = FrontBar;
        GUI.Box(new Rect(screenPosition.x-(healthBarLenght/2),screenPosition.y-20, HPDrop,healthBarHeight),"",style2);
    }



    //Colors for Health system
    public static Texture2D Colors(int r,int g, int b)
    {
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        for (int y = 0; y < texture.height; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < texture.width; ++x)
            {
                Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
                texture.SetPixel(x, y, color);
            }
        }
        texture.Apply();

        return texture;

    }

}
```

This can call from layer script like this

```
void OnGUI(){
        HealthSystem.Set_HealthBar(
            transform,
            2,
            70,
            100,
            HealthSystem.Colors(0,0,0),
            HealthSystem.Colors(0,255,0));
    }
```